# I want to remove "index.html" from url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

converted wordpress site into a static html using httrack. Now I want to remove index.html from my url, but anything I put in .htaccess doesn't work correctly.

example:
(*this is on my test server*)
I want to change page structure url from this:
http: popartcode.space/megalsistemi.com2/o-nama/index.html
to this:
http: popartcode.space/megalsistemi.com2/o-nama/

This is what I tried, it messed up half of my links:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Another try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This changed my link from this:

http: popartcode.space/megalsistemi.com2/o-nama/index.html
to this:

http: popartcode.space/o-nama/

which is not since, since i only need "index.html" removed.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)index\.(php|html)$ /%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but doesn't `(.*)` make `[A-Z]{3,}\s` unnecessary?

Comment: `(.*)` must be part of URI before `index.php`, we don't want to capture `GET` in `%1`